# System.AccessViolation due to Marshal.StructureToPtr

Tags: c#, .net, exception, marshalling

I am using Trhird party tool in my application. On some systems i get the System.AccessViolation error. Although, through code i am not able to reproduce the issue. But in the production environment it does reproduce at some time.

I have the doubt on the following code

```
public static IntPtr TestMarshalToPointer(object value, System.Type type, int length)
{
    int offset = 0;
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(type) * length;
    IntPtr buffer;

    try
    {
        buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        for (var index = 0; index < length; index++)
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(value, new IntPtr(buffer.ToInt32() + offset), false);
            // Its written on MSDN that passing false can lead to memory leak. Please guide , should i need to pass true and how it will affect**
            offset += Marshal.SizeOf(type);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        buffer = (IntPtr)null;
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you provide `true` instead of false?

Comment: Clearly you have to pass false because there is no old structure to delete.

Comment: What does your app target? I hope it's x86 given that ToInt32.

Comment: The structure I am Marshlling is this :   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct MyStructure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer as much as some observations, but it got too long for a comment, so:

1. If you want to return an `IntPtr` that represents `null`, use `IntPtr.Zero`; that's its entire purpose.
2. The `IntPtr` class has an `Add` method that adds an offset to an existing `IntPtr`, which is safer than what you're doing.
3. Since you just allocated your global buffer, and it has no managed reference in it yet, you should continue to pass `false` to `StructureToPtr`; there's nothing for it to free, in any case

Can you tell exactly which line of this code is producing the access violation?

Comment: Thanks Michael for ur valuable inputs..the logging shows the messages till the for loop (e.g. for (var index = 0; index < length; index++)) and then it throws the AccessVioation (Although, not sure b'coz no more logging statements after that, so will put some more of them) ..i have used HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions to handle this..it does not throw the exception from the method i've provided , its throwing from the public method where i've kept the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions attribute...any comment on this?

Comment: In .NET 4, only methods that indicate they can handle corrupted state exceptions will ever get them; if you have such methods in the middle level of a call stack, it will appear as if the exception is being thrown in that method regardless of how deep it actually got thrown. You can turn off this behavior by using the legacy corrupted state exception policy, which might help you debug your problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638517.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is causing the access violation, but this line:

```
Marshal.StructureToPtr(value, new IntPtr(buffer.ToInt32() + offset), false);
```

Seems suspicious. Replacing the code with smarter use of the `IntPtr` class might help:

```
buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
offset = buffer;
for (var index = 0; index < length; index++)
{
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(value, offset, false);
    IntPtr.Add(offset, Marshal.SizeOf(type));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ritch and Michael for your valuable inputs, i will certainly try this but i am unable to reproduce it from the Debug mode so need to check it in the production environment with these changes ...I have used HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions inorder to catch the exception...any comment on this?

Comment: The structure which i am Marshlling is this :                      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct MyStructure

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on 64 bit? The following code will, of course, fail: `buffer.ToInt32()`

You should also call FreeHGlobal after you are done with the buffer. Leave the param as `false`.